# Only click on first 10 items in Selenium element list

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on the first 10 elements from the returned list below.

Currently, Selenium is clicking on all the elements but I want it to be limited to the first 10 clicks only.

How do I do this?

```
items1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']") 
for items in items1:
    items.click()
```

Comment: There are many ways, one way is to just add a counter & if reaches, break the for loop.

Comment: Help with the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
items1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']")
for items in items1[:9]:
    items.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='teams']")
count = 1
for items in items1:
    if count>10:
        break
    items.click()
    count += 1
```

I meant something like this.